# Can't open Jupyter Noteboook on local

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run jupyter from local mac terminal. It used to work but not working when I did some changes in jupyter config file to connect the notebook to a remote server jupyter (which nev er worked without tunneling btw).

```
Here is the changes I did then: 

#  Local IP addresses (such as 127.0.0.1 and ::1) are allowed as local, along
#  with hostnames configured in local_hostnames.
#c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = False

c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True
```

So adding True to allow_remote_access option while keeping the default commented.

But now when I do "jupyter notebook" in termina directory, it keeps showiing opening in browser but never opens.